# Is this proof of $p(z)=0 \iff p(\bar{z})=0$ correct?

Tags: complex-analysis, solution-verification

So, I want to show $p(z)=0 \iff p(\bar{z})=0$. $$p(z)=0\\ \overline{p(z)}=\bar{0}\\p(\bar{z})=0$$

In a previous exercise I have shown that $\overline{p(z)}=p(\overline{z})$, so felt that it was okay to use the conjugate on both sides.

Comment: What is $p(z)$?

Comment: Sorry, $p(z)$ is a polynomial with $z$ as complex input.

Comment: But this will depend on what kind of polynomial. If the coefficients are real then $\overline{p(z)}=p(\overline{z})$ will hold, but otherwise this won't hold.

Comment: @Dave You are correct, I forgot to mention that is has to do with real coefficients.

Comment: In this case the proof is good.

Comment: You should make clear in the proof exactly where you are using the assumption about real coefficients.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your idea is exactly correct. I must make a nitpick, though. Your "proof" is just a sequence of equations, while a proof should consist of complete sentences which form a coherent logical argument. For example, here we are trying to show a biconditional statement, so your proof should clearly explain why $p(z) = 0$ implies $p(\overline{z}) = 0$, and vice versa.

Here's how I would write this proof:

---

Let $z \in \mathbb{C}$ be arbitrary. First, suppose $p(z) = 0$. Then $\overline{p(z)} = \overline{0} = 0$, and we already know $\overline{p(z)} = p(\overline{z})$, so we conclude that $p(\overline{z}) = 0$, as desired. For the reverse direction, suppose $p(\overline{z}) = 0$. Then $\overline{p(\overline{z})} = \overline{0} = 0$, and we know that $\overline{p(\overline{z})} = p(\overline{\overline{z}}) = p(z)$, so we conclude that $p(z) = 0$. We've now shown both directions of implication, so we conclude that $p(z) = 0 \iff p(\overline{z}) = 0$.

---

This might seem overly wordy, and could certainly be made shorter, but (I presume) at this level, a major goal of whatever course you're taking is to get practice writing clear, precise proofs. Most importantly, proofs should always consist of complete sentences! I'll say it again: when you write a proof, you should write entirely in complete sentences. This rule has very few exceptions.

Answer (score 2):

Your proof is correct given that $P(z)$ is a polynomial with real coefficients. If the coefficients are complex $\overline{P(z)} = P(\bar{z})$ doesn't hold. This shows that complex roots occur in conjugate pairs.